# List of days in Objective C

Tags: objective-c, xcode, macos, cocoa, nsdate

I wonder how could I make a list of days from MONDAY to SUNDAY...

I did it so:

```
- (NSString *) stringWithDayNameOf:(int)day {
    NSDateFormatter *dateFormat = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [dateFormat setDateFormat:@"D"];
    NSDate *date = [dateFormat dateFromString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i", day]];
    [dateFormat setDateFormat:@"eeee"];
    NSString* outer = [dateFormat stringFromDate:date];
    outer = [outer uppercaseString];

    return outer;

}


 for (int i = 1; i <= 7; i++) {

        NSLog(@"DAY: %@", [self stringWithDayNameOf:i]);

    }
```

But it displays days from today... How to fix that or make simpler?

Thanks!!

Answer (score 5):

Use `NSDateFormatter`'s `weekdaySymbols` and friends (for short names etc.)

Comment: But what about non-Gregorian days of weeks? Does the `weekdaySymbols` array indexed by the day of week number? (which is probably not since even in Gregorian, the day of week number starts at `1`).

Comment: @adib - `NSDateFormatter` uses an `NSCalendar`, have you tried setting it to a non-Gregorian calendar and seeing what `weekdaySymbols` returns?

Answer (score 2):

`%D` is the format specifier for "day of year", not "day of week". There's no specifier for numerical day of week, since (as far as I know) no-one writes dates that way.

You need to create your date using `NSDateComponents` and then format that:

```
NSDateFormatter *dateFormat = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dateFormat setDateFormat:@"eeee"];
NSCalendar * cal = [NSCalendar currentCalendar];
NSUInteger numWeekdays = [cal maximumRangeOfUnit:NSWeekdayCalendarUnit].length;
NSDateComponents * comp = [[NSDateComponents alloc] init];
for( NSUInteger day = 1; day <= numWeekdays; day++ ){
    [comp setWeekday:day];
    [comp setWeek:0];
    NSDate * date = [cal dateFromComponents:comp];

    NSString * dayName = [dateFormat stringFromDate:date];

    NSLog(@"%@", dayName);
}
```

Also, `NSDateFormatter` knows the names of the days of the week already: [`-[NSDateFormatter weekdaySymbols]`](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSDateFormatter_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000447-CJBFJBHE). The first day of the week in the Gregorian calendar is Sunday.